# Check if sympy expression contains function

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to programmatically determine if a SymPy expression contains `sympy.Function`s? For example, from `a` in

```
from sympy import *

f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

a = f(3) + g(5) + 1.0

print(a)
```

I'd like to get the objects `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`atoms`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.atoms) to find all atoms of a given type:

```
import sympy as sy

f = sy.Function('f')
g = sy.Function('g')

a = f(3) + g(5) + 1.0

print(a)
# f(3) + g(5) + 1.0
print(a.atoms(sy.Function))
```

yields

```
set([f(3), g(5)])
```

To get the `Function` itself,

```
map(type, a.atoms(sy.Function))
```

yields

```
[f, g]
```

Comment: You can also use `a.has(f)` if you only want to check if it is in there or not (and don't care about the value).